# EditText bold content overlap with normal content,bug

Tags: android, android-edittext, richtext

[image]

as the picture shows:
EditText content text contains bold style also contains the normal style, when the normal style text contains a '\ n' character, this time if the bold style of content in a location click on the Enter key, there will be such as Figure of the problem, when I put the normal style of the text '\ n' characters should also be bold style, and then try the above operation, then do not return to the map on the issue,
Has this question been encountered? How should I fix it?

Comment: Edit your question add some code!

Comment: Try and use CData